# Where the implementation of interface methods in Java's Collection Framework take place?

Tags: java, collections, interface

Though I am not very new to Java, the following questions just confused me so much that I cannot overcome this.
I searched a lot on web and found some answers too, but they weren't completely satisfactory.Could anyone please clear my doubts

My confusions are:

```
 1) Vector v = new Vector();  
    v.addElement("A");  
    ........  
    ........  
    Iterator iter = v.iterator();
```

Q1:**Iterator** is an interface and we cannot instantiate or create object to an interface.Then what should we call the "***iter***" here and what is it ?

Q1.1: All the methods of the Iterator(**e.g. next()**) are called by "**iter**". Where are these methods defined? 
      If these methods are defined in a particular inner class of Vector class(as I found on web), what does 
      the iterator() method return ?Cann't we call these methods directly by the object 'v'?

Q1.2: According to Javadoc: Vector implements {Cloneable, Collection, List, RandomAccess, Serializable}
None of these implement Iterator.So how does Vector implements Iterator?

```
 2) In the declaration:  
    List list = new ArrayList();
```

Q1: List is an interface and ArrayList is a class. So new ArrayList() creates an instance of ArrayList.
How can this instance be applied to "list" and AGAIN what is it?

Thanks.....

Comment: Q1.2: `Vector` also implements `Iterable`...

Comment: Q2: You need to read about polymorphism in Java...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't understand what polymorphism is. You also don't understand what "programming to the interface" is. I suspect that Java is your first OO language. To quickly answer - Iterator is an interface but the instance iter is an instance of some class that implements that interface - which class that is doesn't actually matter. The implementation of the methods on Iterator are defined on the implementation of that interface returned by Vector. Vector directly implements Iterator - it's right there in the Javadoc. And again - your last question == "what's polymorphism?"

Comment: @Jon Java is not my first OO language but I was not just much aware about the "programming to the interface" concept.BUT THANK YOU VERY MUCH for your valuable reference for the same.It'll help me a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re 1) `Iterator`s are indeed typically implemented as a private inner class of the corresponding collection class. That's why you can't see the actual implementation class, only the interface. And that is fine, since its implementation details are not the client's concern. You can check its real type in e.g. a debugger though, or look it up in the source code of `Vector`, bundled with your JDK installation.

Vector does not implement `Iterator` itself - it only returns an instance of the inner class mentioned above, from its `iterator` method. This inner class instance has a reference to the `Vector` instance that created it, and sees its internals, that is why it can iterate through its elements. This is why the Iterator pattern is useful: it allows you to iterate through a lot of different collections (or in fact `Iterable`s), without needing to deal with their implementation details.

Re 2) your `list` is exactly what it looks to be: an instance of the `ArrayList` class. The latter implements the `List` interface, thus every `ArrayList` is a `List`.

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

is an example of the idiom "program for interfaces, not for implementations". Since the declared type of `list` above is `List`, you can use it like any other `List` and your subsequent code isn't dependent on its actual implementation. So if it later turns out that instead of an `ArrayList`, it would better to use e.g. a `LinkedList` or a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, you only need to change the one line of code above, and the rest of your code will still work perfectly. Whereas if you declare `list` as

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
```

and later realise its type should be changed, you need at least to go through all the code using `list` and change its type accordingly wherever it is mentioned. Furthermore, some of the code may even use methods specific to `ArrayList`, which aren't available or work differently in the other implementation class, making the change even costlier.

Answer (score 0):

Q1) You can create an instance which implements an interface. `iter` is a reference to an object which must implement `Iterator`

Q1.1) They are implemented as a nested classes. You should be able to see that in the source.

iterator() returns a reference to an Iterator.

Object `v` doesn't implement Iterator.

Q1.2)

> None of these implement Iterator.

which is why you can't call any of the method of an Iterator.

> So how does Vector implements Iterator

it doesn't. AbstractList has a nest class which implements Iterator

Q1) again?

`list` is a reference to an object which must implement List which ArrayList does (or null)

BTW: I wouldn't use Vector unless you have to and I would use generics in examples (they have been around for 8 years now ;)

Comment: It helped.Thanks....and by the way is it true that use of Vector has been deprecated?

Comment: Its not a deprecated class, but I consider it a legacy class like Hashtable or Stack and best avoided.